# Store JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Is there any best practices on how to store actual JQuery selectors?
Not what they return but the selector string itself.
We have tons of selectors in our project, I'd like to have a place or an object for them so I could quickly edit them if needed.

Something like this:

```
LazySelectors = {
    candidate_photo : function() {
        return "#super-duper-selector";
    }
};
```

And then refer to it in many places or different scripts like:

```
$(LazySelectors.candidate_photo()).magic();
```

I've tested this on JSpref and it's a bit faster.
Any best practices or advices?

Comment: `$(LazySelectors.candidate_photo)` should be `$(LazySelectors.candidate_photo())` though. You should run the tests again.

Comment: Why don't you just assign the string to it? No need for a function...

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, didn't notice that while typing. Surely I ran tests on version that worked :)

Comment: Well... maybe you did or maybe you didn't. If you have an additional function call instead of a string literal, I'm quite certain it would not run faster.

Comment: _"I've tested this on JSpref and it's a bit faster"_ - A bit faster than _what_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    LazySelectors  = {
        lazyFormSelector:"#lazyForm",
        createButtonSelector:"#lazyCreateButton",
        idSomeLevel:-1,
    }
    jQuery.extend(SomeOtherObject.LazyObject,LazySelectors);
})
```

and keep this whole LazySelectors object in a different .js file.

You can use it like: `$(SomeOtherObject.LazyObject.lazyFormSelector)`

**One other thing**: As far as i know (i might be wrong here), from a performance point of view,  it is better to cache the "wrapped" DOM element, otherwise you will be traversing the DOM every time you do `$(SomeOtherObject.LazyObject.lazyFormSelector)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it ( *Better Performance* ) , just use string directly, no need for functions.

```
#references.js
var refCandidate_photo = $("#super-duper-selector");
```